# Conditional formatting for dynamically created table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My code reads records from a database and display the records in a dynamically created table. It works fine. But the conditional formatting does not work as intended. For example, I want, if the cell value is "hello", the cell background becomes green. But only the first cell becomes green and cell value is not "hello". What would be the problem?

```js
function dynamicTable() {
  var tableRef = document.getElementById("id_table");
  tableRef.insertRow().innerHTML = "<td id='id_word'>" + word + "</td>" + "<td id='id_count'>" + count + "</td>";

  if (word == “hello“) {
    document.getElementById("id_word").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and the snippet inside (there is a link below the snippet) to add the HTML on which the code runs. Please also include the value of `word` and `count` so that the code does not produce errors. Note that the value of `word` must have been `"hello"` when the code ran, and that only the first cell would become green, because **IDs must be unique to the document**, otherwise only the first is selected by `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, your code will only work for a word that equals "hello", when that is the **first** word. `document.getElementbyID` will return the first element of that id that it finds.

Consider this:

```
function dynamicTable(word, count) {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById("id_table");
    tableRef.insertRow().innerHTML = "<td id='id_word'>" + word + "</td>" + "<td id='id_count'>" + count + "</td>";

    if (word == "hello") {
        document.getElementById("id_word").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}

let words = ["hello", "goodbye", "blah", "blah", "hello", "hello", "something"];

words.forEach((word, i) => {
    dynamicTable(word, i);
});
```

The first cell with word in it will have a green background, but no other cells will.

Perhaps you could create the td separately, give it a style conditionally and then add it to the table afterwards, something like this:

```
function dynamicTable(word, count) {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById("id_table");
    const cell_word = document.createElement("td");
    cell_word.id = "id_word";
    cell_word.innerText = word;
    if (word === "hello") {
        cell_word.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    const cell_count = document.createElement("td");
    cell_count.id = "id_count";
    cell_count.innerText = count;
    tableRef.insertRow().append(cell_word, cell_count);
}

let words = ["hello", "goodbye", "blah", "blah", "hello", "hello", "something"];

words.forEach((word, i) => {
    dynamicTable(word, i);
});
```